# How to plot temperature (of stress) on rectangle bar by matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to plot stress of beam by using matplotlib library.

I have calculated by using formulas and plot it for an example:

[image: Figure 1: Example of before and after of finite element of beam]

As Figure 1, you will see that the green beam has more stress at element 3 and also element 8 Thus if i fill the color by rainbow gradient,The over all of blue beam will be same color but The green beam will have different color by the element 3 and 8 will be going to red side more than others.

[image: example of stress plot]

Here is some of my code and result.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as tri
import numpy as np

node_coordinate = {1: [0.0, 1.0], 2: [0.0, 0.0], 3: [4.018905, 0.87781],
                   4: [3.978008, -0.1229], 5: [1.983549, -0.038322],
                   6: [2.013683, 0.958586], 7: [3.018193, 0.922264],
                   8: [2.979695, -0.079299], 9: [1.0070439, 0.989987],
                   10: [0.9909098, -0.014787999999999999]}
element_stress = {1: 0.2572e+01, 2: 0.8214e+00, 3: 0.5689e+01,
                  4: -0.8214e+00, 5: -0.2572e+01, 6: -0.4292e+01,
                  7: 0.4292e+01, 8: -0.5689e+01}

n = len(element_stress.keys())
x = np.empty(n)
y = np.empty(n)
d = np.empty(n)

for i in element_stress.keys():
    x[i-1] = node_coordinate[i][0]
    y[i-1] = node_coordinate[i][1]
    d[i-1] = element_stress[i]

mask = np.logical_or(x < 1.e20, y < 1.e20)
x = np.compress(mask, x)
y = np.compress(mask, y)
triang = tri.Triangulation(x, y)
cmap = mpl.cm.jet
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(80, 40))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.80, 0.9, 0.15])
cax = ax1.tricontourf(triang, d, cmap=cmap)
fig.colorbar(cax)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot from my code]

You will see that i know all of node co-ordinate and also element's stress value.

But the color of my figure is not smooth and not arrange in horizontal as the example figure above.

How to do as same as it?

p.s. Sorry for my grammar, I'm not native.

Thank you. For suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Increasing the number of contour levels would make the plot appear more smooth. 
E.g. for 101 levels,

```
levels=np.linspace(d.min(), d.max(), num=101)
tri = ax1.tricontourf(triang, d, cmap=cmap, levels=levels)
fig.colorbar(tri)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, If you don't mind can you guide how to transform the color into horizontal as same as the example figure.
Thank you so much.

Comment: You can use `orientation="horizontal"` to make the colorbar horizontal.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingEmest I have try to do it but it doesn't works.

Comment: I have tried it and it does work. Where is the problem?

Comment: You can check my code from my answers ^^ @ImportanceOfBeingEmest

Comment: You can use `orientation="horizontal"` to make the **colorbar** horizontal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145772/discussion-between-yong-bagjns-and-importanceofbeingernest).