# How to plot temperature (thermal gradient) on rectangular block diagram in python? [Python]

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, temperature

I am collecting temperature values from 4 sensors attached to each of the big CPU cores on an Odroid XU4 over time. I want to plot the temperature (thermal gradient) on the block diagram of 4 big cores, shown below:

[image]

So far I have followed [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342311/how-to-plot-temperature-of-stress-on-rectangle-bar-by-matplotlib) on the same issue but I am not being able to fit the solution for mine. I am able to read the temperature values sent from the thermal sensors (sensor 0-4) of the CPU cores as follows:

```
def read_file(fname):
    import string
    with open(fname) as f:
        lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
    sensor0 = []
    sensor1 = []
    sensor2 = []
    sensor3 = []
    for each_line in lines:
        if "sensor0" in each_line:
            this_value = each_line[10:len(each_line)]
            sensor0.append(this_value)
        if "sensor1" in each_line:
            this_value = each_line[10:len(each_line)]
            sensor1.append(this_value)
        if "sensor2" in each_line:
            this_value = each_line[10:len(each_line)]
            sensor2.append(this_value)
        if "sensor3" in each_line:
            this_value = each_line[10:len(each_line)]
            sensor3.append(this_value)
    print("\nProcessed file!\n" + fname)
    reduction = 1000
    sensor0 = map(float, sensor0)
    sensor0V = [temp / reduction for temp in sensor0]
    sensor1 = map(float, sensor1)
    sensor1V = [temp / reduction for temp in sensor1]
    sensor2 = map(float, sensor2)
    sensor2V = [temp / reduction for temp in sensor2]
    sensor3 = map(float, sensor3)
    sensor3V = [temp / reduction for temp in sensor3]

    plot(sensor0V,"Time interval of 0.1 sec on Sensor 0")
    plot(sensor1V,"Time interval of 0.1 sec on Sensor 1")
    plot(sensor2V,"Time interval of 0.1 sec on Sensor 2")
    plot(sensor3V,"Time interval of 0.1 sec on Sensor 3")

def plot(Y,xLabel):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.plot(Y)
    plt.ylabel('Temperature variance over time (0.1 sec)')
    plt.xlabel(xLabel)
    plt.show()

def main():
    fname = "Temp_all.txt"
    read_file(fname)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Currently, using the aforementioned code I am achieving something like this:

[image]

Can anyone help me to plot the temperatures on top of the big cores' block diagram as a thermal gradient over time?

Date stored in each list of sensors is as follows:

> sensor0 = ['6500','7000','8500','8600']. Here 6500 denotes the
>   temperature, 65, in degree Celcius.

An example of thermal gradient is shown in the diagram below:

[image]

Comment: I think this is probably too broad. You don't appear to have made a start on doing the plotting, so there's a lot of ground for us to cover here.

Comment: I guess you need  a 2x2 grid of subplots, one plot for each CPU. Here is an example: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pyplots/pyplot_scales.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-pyplot-scales-py

Comment: Could you include some sample of your data? I don't understand what your want to plot, A thermal gradient for me is a space derivative i.e. dT/dx... Do you want to plot the temperature evolution T(t) as a heatmap wrapped into a square like a [calendar heatmap](https://www.google.com/search?q=calendar+heatmap)?

Comment: sensor0 = ['6500','7000','8500','8600'] is an example of list of temperature stored in each list. Here, 6500 means 65 degree celcius and each entry in the list is taken at 0.1 secs interval.

Comment: @Bazingaa I just had a look at the example but in that I believe that the code is plotting the points in a linear fashion. I am new to python and matplotlib in that sense. Do you happen to know how I may plot temperature with different colours for each CPU?

Comment: @xdze2 I have updated the question with sample data.